# Does a '+' before the first column is ignored or has an impact?

Tags: sql-server, select, operators

This is not really a problem but just want to not stay in ignorance if this operator *may* have an impact of a query.

To make it simple, I had a query like :

```
SELECT 'A', + 'B'
```

The expected result was 'AB'. But because of an unwanted comma before the ' + ', the result was two columns, 'A' and 'B'.

After found this, I'm wondering how SQL Server reads a query like

```
SELECT + 'A'
```

because it returns 'A'. Is this '+' ignored, or interpreted like '' + 'A', or there is in a particular situation an impact on the query ?

Thank you for your attention.

PS, just for fun, because here its easy to see the problem but my case was more :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END, + CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'B' ELSE '' END AS MYFIELD
```

I put 1 = 1 to illustrate that I was sure about my conditions, and *MYFIELD* was returning 'B', just like, without the comma, the two conditions were wrong...

Comment: Based on some tests the operator is not ignored, you can test this by replace `+` to `-` you'll get the error `Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals minus, type equals varchar.` I'm assuming the `+` operator is not ignored but since the left side is nothing it adds nothing.

Comment: Tempted to call this a bug, but the concept of using a typically mathmatical operator for string concatenation is an old and controversial subject. Short answer - don't depend on undocumented functionality.

Comment: If you do this with an actual column and turn on the execution plan, you will also notice that you don't have a `Compute Scalar` which you do have when concatenating strings.

Comment: @SMor Agreed on this but actually I would have had the same question with numbers, like SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 5 END, + CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END AS MYFIELD

Comment: @iguypouf, with numbers it's an [unary_operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) so negative or positive number.